# How to Disable WEB USB Flag in ChromeDriver Selenium in C#?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, web-crawler

Error:
`[3528:3760:0205/072321.889:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(192)] [07:23:21.489] USB: usb_service_win.cc:105  SetupDiGetDeviceProperty({{A45C254E-DF1C-4EFD-8020-67D146A850E0}, 6}) failed: Element not found. (0x490)`

I'm running my application in AWS EC2 Instance and in local it runs fine but not in server.

I'm facing above errors in Console as logs and my application is stuck at this point.

```
Dictionary<string, object> prefs = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "webusb_allow_devices", false }

            };

            browserOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("prefs", prefs);
```

if i use prefs it gives error like
there is already an option for the prefs capabilty.

Then I tried this

```
Dictionary<string, object> prefs = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "webusb_allow_devices", false }

            };

            browserOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("chromeOptions", prefs);
```

Then I got this error:
`OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot parse capability: goog:chromeOptions`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason the answer is marked down, without comment. I believe there are more than two ways of solving any issues and there might be another approach worth trying. Sometimes, the error might not be directly related to the capability itself but rather how it's being passed or interpreted by the Selenium WebDriver.

Try this code sample: Ensure you modify the URL to the URL you would like to navigate.

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

class Program
{


 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Step 1: Create Chrome options
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

        // Step 2: Add arguments to disable webusb
        options.AddArgument("--disable-webusb");

        // Step 3: Create the dictionary to store the Chrome preferences
        var prefs = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {"profile.default_content_setting_values.webusb", 1} // 1 to disable, 2 to enable
        };

        // Step 4: Add the preferences to the Chrome options
        options.AddAdditionalCapability("prefs", prefs);

        // Step 5: Create a Chrome driver instance with the Chrome options
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

        // Now you can use the Chrome driver instance to interact with your application
        // For example, you can navigate to a URL:
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://example.com");

        // Remember to close the driver when you're done
        driver.Quit();
    }
}
```

The above is a C# code.

I have combined the disabling of WebUSB via command-line argument *(--disable-webusb)* and setting the preference through the *prefs* capability. This is to make sure both approaches are taken to disable WebUSB, it might help in cases where the error is related to **capability interpretation or interaction.**

Comment: Thanks for this deep explanation, I really appreciate but I tried this too and there was no change in the issue. This solution was mentioned in other questions too but didn't worked.

Answer (score -1):

Analyzing your error code, the error stated there is already an option for the **"prefs"** capability when trying to add the **"prefs"** capability, it suggests that the **"prefs"** capability might already be set elsewhere in your code or that it's not the correct approach for modifying Chrome options in your Selenium setup.

Therefore, you can directly add the Chrome options using the *"chromeOptions"* capability instead of trying to add them through the **"prefs"** capability. The following example shows how you can modify your code and using the *"chromeOptions"*:

```
// Create a ChromeOptions instance
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

// Add the '--disable-webusb' argument directly to the Chrome options
options.AddArgument("--disable-webusb");

// Pass the Chrome options to the browser options
browserOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("chromeOptions", options);
```

By directly adding the ***--disable-webusb*** argument to the Chrome options and passing them using the ***"chromeOptions"*** capability, you should be able to disable the WEB USB feature in ***ChromeDriver*** Selenium in C# without encountering the error related to the ***"prefs"*** capability.

Also, thinking about setting the ***excludeSwitches*** capability that might really work like:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddExcludedArgument("enable-features=WebUSB");
```

but below approach is much better:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Step 1: Create Chrome options and add the --disable-webusb argument
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArgument("--disable-webusb");

        // Step 2: Create a Chrome driver instance with the Chrome options
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

        // Now you can use the Chrome driver instance to interact with your application
        // For example, you can navigate to a URL:
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://example.com");

        // Remember to close the driver when you're done
        driver.Quit();
    }
}
```

This will make sure that Chrome options are correctly configured to disable WEB USB and passed to the ChromeDriver instance, resolving the issue you have encountered.